# Call function in controller from eventlistener in .run

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, ionic-popup

Using Ionic v1, I am trying to call a function in my controller when an event listener in my app.run fires. The event is created by a Cordova (Phonegap) plugin that detects changes in the headphone jack.

I must be doing something wrong because I can't find a solution that works. Here is my example:

```
(function() {
 var app = angular.module('mymodule', ['ionic']);
    app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
           if(window.HeadsetDetection){
                /*Monitor for changes in the headphone jack*/
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                  window.HeadsetDetection.registerRemoteEvents(function(status){
                    // *HERE* is where I want to call or somehow trigger 
                        an action in my controller
                 });
                }, false);
              }
        });
  });
```

When the headphone jack is sensed I am trying to close an ionic popup created in my controller.

Comment: what plugin are you using for headphone detection ? is it : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/HeadsetDetection-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Yep https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/HeadsetDetection-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your events from `.run` part of your angular application.

Therefore; to communicate with a controller; you need to use :
 - a global variable ($rootScope) on your app that is watched in your controller : this is an ugly solution; that I do not recommand
 - Broadcast / on an event in your app:  this is the clean solution

You need ; when you detect the event to broadcast to your app the news :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('headphones-Updated');
```

Within your controller; you have juste now to catch the event :

```
$scope.$on('headphones-Updated', function(event, args) {


});
```

Another solution would have to set your event listener right in the controller

Comment: I tried that, but I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined

Comment: You shall inject $rootScope .  app.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope) {

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to Ionic/Angular.